# Counting number of occurrences in Foreign Key relationships

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, count, django-queryset

I have the following models set up:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    # stuff

class Alliance(models.Model):
    # an alliance is made up of 3 teams
    teams = models.ManyToManyField(Team)

class Match(models.Model):
    # 2 alliances per match
    alliances = models.ManyToManyField(Alliance)
    # 1 winner per match
    winner = models.ForeignKey(Alliance, related_name='winner')
```

I am trying to find which teams and alliances have the most wins. I have successfully gotten alliances to work through this:

```
from collections import Counter
def most_alliance_wins():
    matches = Match.objects.all()
    count = Counter()
    for m in matches:
        count[m.winner] += 1
    # Remove ties
    del count[None]
    return count.most_common(5)
```

However, my teams wins method won't work, saying that I can't access the manager for the model, but I'm not sure where in the code I'm actually trying to access the manager, so I'm a bit lost.

```
from collections import Counter
def most_team_wins():
    matches = Match.objects.all()
    count = Counter()
    for m in matches:
        for team in m.winner.objects.all():
            count[team] += 1
    return count.most_common(5)
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated

Comment: It might be better to post the answer to your question as an answer instead of an edit to share Q/A style for someone who may have this same problem in the future.

Comment: Okay, I'll do that.

Comment: Yes, I left out a couple of things like that for the question. It all works properly from my test cases thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, I'm dumb. Solved!

This is the solution:

```
def most_wins():
    matches = Match.objects.all()
    count = Counter()
    for m in matches:
        if m.winner is None:
            continue
        for team in m.winner.teams.all():
            count[team] += 1
    return count.most_common(5)
```

I should have been referencing `m.winner.teams.all()` instead of `m.winner.objects.all()`.

Comment: While this answer may work, it's going to be a database killer. Note how you begin by fetching all the Match objects. If there are hundreds of thousands of records you are getting a lot of data. Secondly note how you are having a nested loop. And in your nested loop you are doing a nested loop. A nested loop is rarely the right solution to fetch data

Comment: What might you recommend instead? I'll probably have between 70-110,000 entries for the Match table, and I'm using MariaDB/MySQL rather than SQLite.

Comment: Post the real models and I will try to have a crack at it.